# How to make synchronous counter that counts 3,5,7,0 and repeats?

Tags: digital, circuit

How to make synchronous counter that counts 3,5,7,0 and repeats?

I'm assuming I'll need three T-flip-flops?

Comment: Construct the truth table with the 3 input bits and the 3 next state output bits.  Then construct the Karnaugh maps for the 3 next state output bits.  From those, determine the minimized Product Of Sums or Sum of Products, and from that design the gate & flip-flop circuit.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, you could get it simpler if treat in another way: two upper bits are circling 0,1,2,3, and lower one is OR of upper ones.

Something like (pseudocode)

```
wire V[1:0];
wire Out[2:0];
@(posedge clk) {
  V += 1;
  Out[2] <= V[1]; Out[1] <= V[0]; Out[0] <= V[1] | V[0];
}
```

Comment: Initial state is wrong.  OP is asking for the digital design.